# jQuery pass object out of one function to another

Tags: jquery, function, object, fade

I've made a small function that I'll be reusing several times in an application. It seems like I've written the syntax wrong because my console is showing an eror "Object [object Object] has no method 'fadeIt'

So I imagine the issue is passing the object of one function into another.. not sure how to do it gracefully. My code is below.

Thanks for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/aFx6u/2/

```
function fadeIt() {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:0
    }, 400, function(){
        //$(this).css('cursor','auto');
        //$(this).children('img').css('margin-left','-100px');
    });
}

$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeIt();
}):
```

Comment: why not just use jQuery's `fadeOut()` function?

Comment: This'll help you sort it out: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: @rjz - going to combine some other goodies where the comments are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to make this into a plugin and use the following approach:

$.fn.fadeIt = function() {

};

then you can use $(this).fadeIt();

Answer (score 1):

You can set the calling context of the `fadeIt` function by using `.call()`, like this...

```
fadeIt.call(this)
```

---

***Explanation:***

JavaScript has two methods, `.call()` and `.apply()` that both let you manually set the value of `this` in the function you're invoking, at the time of invocation.

The `.call()` and `.apply()` methods are available on all JavaScript functions for this purpose.

The first argument to the method is the value you want to set for `this` in the function you're invoking. The only difference between the two is how the arguments are passed.

---

With `.call()`, the arguments are passed individually, like...

```
func.call(thisArg, 'foo', 'bar')
```

With `.apply()` the arguments are passed as an Array-like collection...

```
func.apply(thisArg, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

...which will be destructured as individual arguments in the function being invoked.

Comment: Neat. I don't think I knew about this, and if I did I forgot about it.

Comment: @GregPettit: Yes, it comes in *very* handy at times.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your code.

```
function fadeIt(element) {
    element.animate({
        opacity:0
    }, 400, function() {
        // element.css('cursor','auto');
        // element.children('img').css('margin-left','-100px');
    });
}

$('.box').click(function() {
    fadeIt($(this));
}):
```

However, I would strongly recommend using jQuery's built in functions like [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) instead.

Comment: A plugin or existing functions are ultimately better, but this directly answers the question. A bit of explanation instead of just code is better for answers, but I'd like to know who downvoted it and why.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is call a function using dot notation, which in Javascript is limited only to an object's prototype. What you want to do is change it so you pass the `this` as an argument in fadeIt

```
function fadeIt(obj) {
...
}
```

then call `fadeIt($(this));`